# Can you give key values to array Objects in a JS Object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jackson

So I have an AJAX call that retreives a JS object from and it is something like this:

```
{
    Record1: {
        key1: value1
    },
    Record2: {
        key2: value2
    },
    SubRecords: [
        {
            ID: alpha,
            subkey1: subval-1,
            subkey2: subval-2
        },
        {
            ID: beta,
            subkey3: subval-3,
            subkey4: subval-4
        },
        {
            ID: beta,
            subkey3: subval-5,
            subkey4: subval-6
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to push this to Knockout.js so that is can populate a group of fields mapped to corrosponding fields (and fields can have multiples on the UI). Is it possible for Jackson or Knockout to move the `ID: beta` outside of the object within the array to identify it in Knockout as `beta: {ID: beta, subkey3: ...}`

Comment: Will write you jsfiddle in next 5 mins for this. And yes, it is possible. But may I pls use pure query only for that?

Comment: Sure! @JakubPolomský I just need something to kick off of.